# Prevent sending email and show message via plug-in

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2011

I am writing crm2011 plugin in "Email" entity with "Send" Message of Pre_operation. What i want to do is when i click "Send" button in email entity, I do the necessary checking before send. If the checking is not correct, I want to prevent and stop the sending email and show "the alert message" and stop the second plugin(this plugin send email and create the associated entity to convert "Case"). Please give me some suggestion for that plugin?
Should i use pre-Validation stage or Pre_operation state? And how can I return false to stop plugin.

```
  public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        try
        {
            string message = null;
            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
            _context = (IPluginExecutionContext)
                                         serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

            _serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
            _currentUser = _context.UserId;
            message = _context.MessageName.ToLower();
            if (message == "send")
            {
                if (_context.InputParameters != null && _context.InputParameters.Contains("EmailId"))
                {
                    object objEmailId = _context.InputParameters["EmailId"];
                    if (objEmailId != null)
                    {
                        _emailId = new Guid(objEmailId.ToString());
                        FindEmailInfo();
                        if (_email != null)
                        {
                            if (_email.Attributes.Contains("description") && _email.Attributes["description"] != null)//Email descritpion is not null
                            {
                                string emaildescription = StripHTML();

                                //Find KB Article prefix no in system config entity
                                serviceguideprefix = "ServiceGuidesPrefix";
                                QueryByAttribute query = new QueryByAttribute("ppp_systemconfig");
                                query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true);
                                query.AddAttributeValue(sysconfig_name, serviceguideprefix);
                                EntityCollection sysconfig = _service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
                                if (sysconfig.Entities.Count > 0)
                                {
                                    Entity e = sysconfig.Entities[0];
                                    if (e.Attributes.Contains("ppp_value"))
                                    {
                                        ppp_value = e.Attributes["ppp_value"].ToString();
                                    }
                                }
                                if (ppp_value != null && ppp_value != string.Empty)
                                {
                                    //var matches = Regex.Matches(emaildescription, @"KBA-\d*-\w*").Cast<Match>().ToArray();
                                    var matches = Regex.Matches(emaildescription, ppp_value + @"-\d*-\w*").Cast<Match>().ToArray();
                                    //ReadKBNo(emaildescription);
                                    foreach (Match kbnumber in matches)
                                    {
                                        EntityCollection kbarticlecol = FindKBArticleIds(kbnumber.ToString());
                                        if (kbarticlecol.Entities.Count > 0)
                                        {
                                            Entity kbariticle = kbarticlecol.Entities[0];
                                            if (kbariticle.Attributes.Contains("mom_internalkm"))
                                            {
                                                bool internalserviceguide = (bool)kbariticle.Attributes["mom_internalkm"];
                                                if (internalserviceguide) found = true;
                                                else found = false;
                                            }
                                            else found = false;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                if (found)
                                {
                                    //-----
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(ex.Message, ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well stopping the plugin is dead easy you just throw InvalidPluginException, the message you give it will be shown to the user in a alert window. You will have to do this on the pre of the send. In this case I don't think it will matter if its pre-validation or pre-operation.

Edit:

Yes, you should throw an InvalidPluginException even if no exception has happened in code. I accept this isnt what we would normally do, but its the way its meant to work. Msdn has more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334685.aspx

So for example the code would look like:

```
public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    try    
    {
        //This is where we validate the email send
        if(emailIsOkay)
        {
            //Do something
        }
        else if(emailIsNotOkay)
        {
            //Throw and exception that will stop the plugin and the message will be shown to the user (if its synchronous)
            throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("Hello user, your email is not correct!!");
        }
    }
    catch (InvalidPluginExecutionException invalid)
    {
        //We dont to catch exception for InvalidPluginExecution, so just throw them on
        throw; 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //This exception catches if something goes wrong in the code, or some other process.
        throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(ex.Message, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi James, please let me explain detail to throw InvalidPluginException message. In my plugin code, i set boolean value(found) for checking. If checking is wrong(found == true), I should throw exception and show message although there is no error exception in plugin? I also attached my plugin code in original email. please see and give me some suggestion.

Comment: Hi i've update my post, but yes you show throw an exception even if there is no error in the plugin.

Comment: James, I am have an extended scenario from this. I am having a log entity and i am writing my validation errors to that entity in this plugin and if such errors exists i am throwing exception as above. But the problem is my log entries are also rolled back it seems. Basically those records are not created when i am throwing this exception. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score -4):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Crm;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using System.ServiceModel;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;
using Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace SendEmail
{
    public class Email : IPlugin
    {
        public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceprovider)
        {

            IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceprovider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
            if (!(context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity))
                return;

            //entity
            Entity ent = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];
            if (ent.LogicalName != "entityName")//EntityName
                throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("Not a Service Request record! ");

            //service
            IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceprovider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
            IOrganizationService _service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
             string Email="";

            if (ent.Contains("emailidfiled"))
               Email = (string)ent["emailidfiled"];



            #region email template
            QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression()
            {
                EntityName = "template",
                Criteria = new FilterExpression(LogicalOperator.And),
                ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true)
            };
            query.Criteria.AddCondition("title", ConditionOperator.Equal, "templateName");

            EntityCollection _coll = _service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
            if (_coll.Entities.Count == 0)
                throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("Unable to find the template!");
            if (_coll.Entities.Count > 1)
                throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("More than one template found!");

            var subjectTemplate = "";
            if (_coll[0].Contains("subject"))
            {
                subjectTemplate = GetDataFromXml(_coll[0]["subject"].ToString(), "match");
            }
            var bodyTemplate = "";
            if (_coll[0].Contains("body"))
            {
                bodyTemplate = GetDataFromXml(_coll[0]["body"].ToString(), "match");
            }
            #endregion



            #region email prep
            Entity email = new Entity("email");
            Entity entTo = new Entity("activityparty");
            entTo["addressused"] =Email;
            Entity entFrom = new Entity("activityparty");
            entFrom["partyid"] = "admin@admin.com";
            email["to"] = new Entity[] { entTo };
            email["from"] = new Entity[] { entFrom };
            email["regardingobjectid"] = new EntityReference(ent.LogicalName, ent.Id);
            email["subject"] = subjectTemplate;
            email["description"] = bodyTemplate;
            #endregion

            #region email creation & sending
            try
            {
                var emailid = _service.Create(email);
                SendEmailRequest req = new SendEmailRequest();
                req.EmailId = emailid;
                req.IssueSend = true;
                GetTrackingTokenEmailRequest wod_GetTrackingTokenEmailRequest = new GetTrackingTokenEmailRequest();
                GetTrackingTokenEmailResponse wod_GetTrackingTokenEmailResponse = (GetTrackingTokenEmailResponse)
                                                                 _service.Execute(wod_GetTrackingTokenEmailRequest);
                req.TrackingToken = wod_GetTrackingTokenEmailResponse.TrackingToken;
                _service.Execute(req);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("Email can't be saved / sent." + Environment.NewLine + "Details: " + ex.Message);
            }
            #endregion



        }


        private static string GetDataFromXml(string value, string attributeName)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }

            XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(value);
            // get the Element with the attribute name specified
            XElement element = document.Descendants().Where(ele => ele.Attributes().Any(attr => attr.Name == attributeName)).FirstOrDefault();
            return element == null ? string.Empty : element.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What about some explanation how this code solves the problem? Just posting code does not help anyone.

Comment: this post regarding send email.1.create a template in crm 2011 2.then retrieve  that template from query expression "templateName"