# How to use a plugin to stop user from saving?

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm creating a plugin that I want to search through previous records for the same account and if there is already one open, then when they click on the save button to save this new record then the plugin should cancel the save. Is this possible in a C# plugin? I know it can be done in JavaScript but I've never done it in a plugin before.

Comment: Very similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821951/prevent-sending-email-and-show-message-in-email-entity-with-send-execution-of/11823637#11823637

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can throw an exception box (InvalidPluginExecutionException) from the plugin and have a friendly message inside it saying something like "account already exists", this would stop it from saving, don't know if that is something you are looking for ?

Comment: This sounds like it could work, would the code need to be fired in either the pre-validation or pre-operation stages to stop it from saving? Or will it work in post-operation still?

Comment: Just answered my own question by trying it actually! Yeah it works, I wouldn't have thought of throwing an error to stop it but it does make sense. Thanks for your help